# Extend a grid within a form to full height

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a Form panel with a grid in it. I want that the grid consumes the available space and appends a scrollbar if this space is not enough for all the data. But that does not work, the grid just grow with each new data and will also grow out of sight without any scrollbar. How can I configure this set to behave like described above?

Here is the form with the grid:

```
{
    xtype: 'form',
    plain: true,
    autoScroll: true,
    border: 0,
    bodyPadding: 5,
    // which layout would I use Here? I tried anchor and vbox already
    layout: '???'
    items: [{
        xtype: 'hidden',
        name: 'SomeHidden'
    }, {
        xtype: 'hidden',
        name: 'SomeHiddenId'
    }, {
        xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            align: 'stretch'
        },
        items: [ /*The form fields*/ ]
    }, {
        // --> this grid should consume all available space 
        // and append a scrollbar if the content still grows to much
        xtype: 'grid',
        hidden: this.stepIdent == 3,
        autoScroll: true,
        store: Ext.StoreMgr.lookup('JournalStore'),
        features: [{
            ftype: 'summary'
        }],
        columns: [ /*col data*/ ]

    }]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a vbox layout:

```
Ext.require('*');

Ext.onReady(function() {

    var store = new Ext.data.Store({
        fields: ['name'],
        data: []
    });

    new Ext.form.Panel({
        width: 400,
        height: 600,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            align: 'stretch'
        },
        items: [{
            fieldLabel: 'Field 1',
            xtype: 'textfield'
        }, {
            fieldLabel: 'Field 2',
            xtype: 'textfield'
        }, {
            fieldLabel: 'Field 3',
            xtype: 'textfield'
        }, {
            fieldLabel: 'Field 4',
            xtype: 'textfield'
        }, {
            flex: 1,
            xtype: 'gridpanel',
            store: store,
            columns: [{
                flex: 1,
                dataIndex: 'name'
            }]
        }] 
    });

    var i = 0;
    setInterval(function(){
        store.add({
            name: 'Item ' + (++i)
        });
    }, 1000);

});
```

Comment: In my case I had a window which wrapps up the form and get sized to fullscreen but anyway this helped me solving it!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code. Main idea is that form has `anchor layout` and gridpanel has `anchor: 0 0` for stretch grid vertically and horizontally

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyForm', {
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',

height: 294,
width: 458,
title: 'My Form',

initComponent: function() {
    var me = this;

    Ext.applyIf(me, {
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'gridpanel',
                anchor: '0 0',
                title: 'My Grid Panel',
                columns: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                        dataIndex: 'string',
                        text: 'String'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'numbercolumn',
                        dataIndex: 'number',
                        text: 'Number'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'datecolumn',
                        dataIndex: 'date',
                        text: 'Date'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'booleancolumn',
                        dataIndex: 'bool',
                        text: 'Boolean'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    });

    me.callParent(arguments);
}
```

});

Answer (score -1):

make the form panel layout as fit

Comment: fit layout only support one child (more get layered)